# Riemann Integral Help

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

My Question today is:

Define g : [−3, 2] → $\mathbb{R}$ by g(x) = 6x + 1. Use the definition of the Riemann integral
to show that g is integrable on [−3, 2] and determine the value of the integral $\int_{-3}^{2} g(x) dx$.

I understand the definition of a Riemann Integral but cant seem to be able to apply it to this question. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Consider a partition of $[-3, 2]$ first into just two subintervals, $[-3, a], [a, 2]$.  What are the upper and lower Riemann sums on the partition $-3, a, 2$?  You will get algebraic expressions in terms of $a$.

Comment: so would U(g,$P_n$) be $\sum_{k=1}^{n} (6(5k/n)+1)(5/n)$? @avs

Comment: With $P_n$ being the partition and k being substitiuted for **a** @avs

Comment: yeah ive taken that into account. Is my statement above about U(g,$P_n$) correct?? @AbdallahHammam

Comment: Oh I see now. Would it now be: U(g,$P_n$) = $\sum_{k=1}^{n} (6(-3+5k/n)+1)(5/n)$?? @AbdallahHammam

Comment: @OPFragster Seems fine now.

Comment: So ive simplified it down to (5/n)$\sum_{k=1}^{n} (30k/n)-17$ do i then take the sum of 30k/n and -17 like: $\sum_{k=1}^{n} (30k/n)$-$\sum_{k=1}^{n} 17$ and work from there?? @AbdallahHammam

Comment: @OPFragster Is it ok .

Comment: @OPFragster, yes, that was what I was driving towards.  I only suggested a small partition (two subintervals) because it is sufficiently simple to write out $L$ and $U$ easily, and yet it gives an idea of how to generalize to $n>2$.

Answer (score 1):

$g$ is increasing at $[-3,2]$.

let $n>0$ and  $$(x_k=-3+k\frac{5}{n})_{k=0,1...n}$$ be a regular partition of $[-3,2]$.

then

$$U(g,n)=\frac{5}{n}\sum_{k=1}^ng(x_i)$$

$$L(g,n)=\frac{5}{n}\sum_{k=1}^ng(x_{i-1})$$

and by telescopage,

$$U(g,n)-L(g,n)=\frac{5}{n}(g(2)-g(-3))$$

$$=\frac{150}{n}.$$

thus

for each $\epsilon>0,\;\;$ if we take

$$N=\lfloor \frac{150}{\epsilon} \rfloor +1,$$

then

$$U(g,N)-L(g,N)<\epsilon.$$

and $\;g\;$ is Riemann integrable at $[-3,2]$.